# Changing FirstPersonController MouseLook sensitivity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am an absolute beginner. I am currently making an aim down sights script with javascript, and when aiming I want the sensitivity for both x and y to drop to 2. I tried using

```
GetComponent.<UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.MouseLook>().sensitivityX = 2;
```

but that doesn't work. The error for that line is

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.GetDispatcher (System.Object target, System.String cacheKeyName, System.Type[] cacheKeyTypes, Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.DispatcherFactory factory)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.GetDispatcher (System.Object target, System.Object[] args, System.String cacheKeyName, Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.DispatcherFactory factory)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.SetProperty (System.Object target, System.String name, System.Object value)
AimDownSights.Update () (at Assets/AimDownSights.js:33)
```

Does anyone know how to access the reference the Mouse Look dropdown in FPSController so I can change sensitivity? Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any error? What do you mean by *"it does not work"*?

Comment: @Programmer I edited the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should be using *C#* as soon as possible because it has more features than Javascript. Also, you will get more help with C# than Unityscript. Finally, the chances of Unityscript being discontinued in the future is high so make that decision now. You can find C# tutorial for Unity [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting).

The `MouseLook` script is not not exposed in the  `FirstPersonController` script.

We will expose the `MouseLook`. Open the `FirstPersonController.cs` script from *Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/FirstPersonCharacter/Scripts* directory and add the script below to it:

```
public MouseLook mouseLookCustom
{
    get { return m_MouseLook; }
}
```

That's it. We have now exposed the `MouseLook` instance.

---

**To modify the mouse stuff:**

**C#:**

```
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

public class Fpstest : MonoBehaviour
{
    FirstPersonController fps;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject fpObj = GameObject.Find("FPSController");
        fps = fpObj.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>();
        fps.mouseLookCustom.XSensitivity = 5;
    }
}
```

**Unityscript/Javascript**:

```
#pragma strict
import UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

var fps:FirstPersonController;

function Start () {
    var fpObj = GameObject.Find("FPSController");
    fps = GetComponent.<FirstPersonController>();
    fps.mouseLookCustom.XSensitivity = 5;
}
```

Comment: Very good answer!  I started Unity this week, and since I already know Javascript, I am currently using.  I have plans to learn C#, but I want to learn the feel of Unity before diving into a new language